# Are Developer Tools availabe in every Chromium-based application and if yes, how to open them?

Tags: chromium-embedded

I have a CEF-based application, written by a previous engineer, with no source code. For debugging and changing some server code, I'd like to have an option to open Developer Tools for the application, which are disabled. Is there a way to re-enable and start them? As far as I know, for CEF-based applications they are included anyway, even if a developer chooses to disable them.

Comment: No, if the "inspect element"  right-mouse context menu item from CefClient is not present there might or might not be any way to enable the tools.  If it's CefSharp it might be easy to decompile the app back to some form of source code , but native C++ is going to be harder and the results will be somewhat cryptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run that app with the command line parameter

```
app.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

It will start your app instance with the remote-debugging-port, then you can open `http://localhost:9222` in Chrome and you will find the Developer Tools interface identical to the embedded one.

Comment: It's worth a try (and upvoted), but some CEF apps remove/ignore command line arguments for security reasons.